# Memory Allocation - UI Stucks/Hangs - While Network Call (Rx2AndroidNetworking)& Inserting Records In SQLite(ActiveAndroid)

Tags: android-sqlite, retrofit, retrofit2, okhttp, activeandroid

I am using `Rx2AndroidNetworking` in my project to get `getObjectListObservable` thousands of records from the Server JSON List of Objects about 150+ attributes of SQLite Database of 3 Tables which i have to  resync(Insert) the data to SQLite tables using ActiveAndroid ORM.

While executing the `Rx2AndroidNetworking.get` method the following logs are showing in the logcat.

```
D/LoginActivity: onCompleted: only_login
D/LoginActivity: onComplete: before_executing_the_resyncing_code
D/LoginActivity: InsertData: before_Rx2AndroidNetworking_GetPatients
I/art: Do partial code cache collection, code=57KB, data=58KB
I/art: After code cache collection, code=56KB, data=57KB
I/art: Increasing code cache capacity to 256KB
I/art: Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 12747(2MB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 11% free, 17MB/19MB, paused 12.598ms total 37.164ms
```

While executing the `public void onNext` method the following logs are showing in the logcat.

```
D/LoginActivity: onNext: resyncing_insert_data_in db
I/art: Do full code cache collection, code=125KB, data=101KB
I/art: Starting a blocking GC JitCodeCache
I/art: After code cache collection, code=69KB, data=44KB
I/art: Do partial code cache collection, code=81KB, data=80KB
I/art: After code cache collection, code=80KB, data=80KB
I/art: Increasing code cache capacity to 512KB
I/art: Compiler allocated 6MB to compile void .onNext(java.util.List)
I/art: Compiler allocated 8MB to compile void .onNext(java.util.List)
```

While executing network call and inserting the data in the SQLite the UI of my App is stucks. My app wants to get Memory from the OS but the device (Lenovo TB-X704L having 3 GB RAM) unable to allocate more than of 64 MB of memory to my app(screenshot is attached hereby).

[image]

Diagnose the issue and suggest the solution.

Answer (score 0):

On which thread you are doing sql operation? Try to move sql operation on separate worker thread.